# Could not open library 'vips.42' - Ruby/Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, vips

Everything was running smoothly until... I ran into this error when running the `brew upgrade vips` command:

```
bundle exec jekyll s -l
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/bin/jekyll)
/Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.16.1/lib/ffi/dynamic_library.rb:65:in `load_library': Could not open library 'vips.42': dlopen(vips.42, 0x0005): tried: 'vips.42' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSvips.42' (no such file), '/usr/lib/vips.42' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'vips.42' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/vips.42' (no such file), '/usr/lib/vips.42' (no such file, not in dyld cache). (LoadError)
Could not open library 'libvips.42.dylib': dlopen(libvips.42.dylib, 0x0005): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib
  Referenced from: <555C8E69-E957-3A35-BB01-AF28A62E44B4> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmatio/1.5.23/lib/libmatio.11.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache).
Could not open library '/usr/local/lib/libvips.42.dylib': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libvips.42.dylib, 0x0005): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib
  Referenced from: <555C8E69-E957-3A35-BB01-AF28A62E44B4> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmatio/1.5.23/lib/libmatio.11.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache).
Could not open library '/opt/homebrew/lib/libvips.42.dylib': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libvips.42.dylib, 0x0005): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib
  Referenced from: <555C8E69-E957-3A35-BB01-AF28A62E44B4> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmatio/1.5.23/lib/libmatio.11.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.14.2/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache).
Searched in <system library path>, /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, /opt/local/lib, /opt/homebrew/lib
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.16.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:95:in `block in ffi_lib'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.16.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:94:in `map'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.16.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:94:in `ffi_lib'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.17/lib/vips.rb:528:in `<module:Vips>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.17/lib/vips.rb:525:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.17/lib/ruby-vips.rb:1:in `require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.17/lib/ruby-vips.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll_picture_tag-2.0.4/lib/jekyll_picture_tag/images/generated_image.rb:1:in `require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll_picture_tag-2.0.4/lib/jekyll_picture_tag/images/generated_image.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll_picture_tag-2.0.4/lib/jekyll_picture_tag/images.rb:2:in `require_relative'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll_picture_tag-2.0.4/lib/jekyll_picture_tag/images.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll_picture_tag-2.0.4/lib/jekyll_picture_tag.rb:5:in `require_relative'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll_picture_tag-2.0.4/lib/jekyll_picture_tag.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler.rb:176:in `require'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:53:in `require_from_bundler'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:484:in `exec'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/2.7.3/gems/bundler-2.3.6/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /Users/gschiavon/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

From what I understand there is a misconfigured path to the library `vips.42` but upon checking the folder, it indeed doesn't exist.

#### Which VIPS

`/opt/homebrew/bin/vips`

#### Ruby -v

`ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [arm64-darwin20]`

#### System

MacBookPro M1
OSX Ventura 13.4

I can provide more config info as required.  someone can please help!

Comment: See https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/371